# My drop down list is not showing

Tags: ionic-framework

**HTML Code**

```
<ion-buttons end>
    <button ion-button clear (click)="toggleFilterSort()">
        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>                    
    </button>            
</ion-buttons>
```

**TS File**

```
toggleFilterSort() {
        this.viewCtrl.getContent().scrollTo(0, 0);
        let toggle = this.popoverCtrl.create(
                ToggleModel, 
                {toggleMenu: this.toggleMenu},
                {
                    cssClass: 'oFilter',
                    enableBackdropDismiss: true,
                    showBackdrop: true
                }
            );
        toggle.onDidDismiss(data=>{
            if(data != null && data.toggleMenu) {
                this.toggleMenu = data.toggleMenu;
            }
        });
        console.log(this.toggleMenu);
    }
```

**Code to call another html file which show the 2 tabs in a drop down list called Filter & Sort**

```
<div [ngClass]="{toggles: true}">
    <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="toggleMenu" (ionChange)="fSelect()">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label><div class="toggleMenu-item">Filter</div></ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="filter"  (ionSelect)="toggleMenu='filter'"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label><div class="toggleMenu-item">Sort</div></ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="sort" (ionSelect)="toggleMenu='sort'" ></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</div>
```

This is an example of the app I wanna create [image: here], but I can't show a drop-down list when user click on the ellipsis icon. There are no errors found in my console too so I do not know which line of code is wrong. Why does my dropdown list not showing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the [present method](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/popover/PopoverController/#presenting) after creating the popover. See updated code below.

```
toggleFilterSort() {
    this.viewCtrl.getContent().scrollTo(0, 0);
    let toggle = this.popoverCtrl.create(
        ToggleModel, 
        {toggleMenu: this.toggleMenu},
        {
            cssClass: 'oFilter',
            enableBackdropDismiss: true,
            showBackdrop: true
        }
    );


    toggle.present({
        ev: myEvent
    });


    toggle.onDidDismiss(data=>{
        if(data != null && data.toggleMenu) {
            this.toggleMenu = data.toggleMenu;
        }
    });
    console.log(this.toggleMenu);
}
```